# data-request-update : OctoberCMS

Tags: html, laravel, octobercms

For those who know the data in html5 or for those who know October CMS, here is my question: Is data-request-update always done, whether the result of the data request? If I ask my question otherwise: When does the data-request-update not run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The data-request-update attribute will only run when the relative data-request method has returned. It doesn't matter if a 400 error is returned or a 200. October will update the elements with the partials specified regardless.

Comment: The update code cannot run when an error 500 code is returned, this is why we have the `AjaxException` class that returns error 406 instead.